# Attempting to call an array and setting the value from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This class here is creating a student object:

```
public class Student {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int assignmentScores[];
    int labScores[];
    int attendanceScore;
    int totalHomeworkScore;
    int midterm1;
    int midterm2;
    int finalExam;
    int zyanteScore;
    int patScore;
    int totalTestScore;
    String letterGrade;

    public Student() {

    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName = fName;

    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lName) {

        lastName = lName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setAssignmentScores(int[] assignmentScore) {
        assignmentScores = assignmentScore;
    }

    public int[] getAssignmentScores() {
        return assignmentScores;
    }

    public void setLabScores(int[] labScore) {
        assignmentScores = labScore;
    }

    public int[] getLabScores() {
        return labScores;
    }

    public void setAttendanceScore(int attenScore) {
        attendanceScore = attenScore;
    }

    public int getAttendanceScore() {
        return attendanceScore;
    }

    public void setTotalHomeworkScore(int hScore) {
        totalHomeworkScore = hScore;
    }

    public int getTotalHomeworkScore() {
        return totalHomeworkScore;
    }

    public void setMidTerm1(int mT1) {
        midterm1 = mT1;
    }

    public int getMidterm1() {
        return midterm1;
    }

    public void setMidterm2(int mT2) {
        midterm2 = mT2;
    }

    public int getMidterm2() {
        return midterm2;
    }

    public void setFinalExam(int fExam) {
        finalExam = fExam;
    }

    public int getFinalExam() {
        return finalExam;
    }

    public void setZyanteScore(int zyant) {
        zyanteScore = zyant;
    }

    public int getZyanteScore() {
        return zyanteScore;
    }

    public void setPatScore(int pat) {
        patScore = pat;
    }

    public int getPatScore() {
        return patScore;
    }

    public void setTotalTestScore(int tScore) {
        totalTestScore = tScore;
    }

    public int getTotalTestScore() {
        return totalTestScore;
    }

    public void computeGrade() {
        if (getTotalHomeworkScore() <= 599 || getTotalTestScore() <= 149
                || getTotalHomeworkScore() <= 719 && getTotalTestScore() <= 179
                || getTotalHomeworkScore() <= 779 && getTotalTestScore() <= 164
                || getTotalHomeworkScore() <= 659 && getTotalTestScore() <= 209) {
            letterGrade = "P";
        }

        if (getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 1140 && getTotalTestScore() >= 180
                || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 1080
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 195 || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 960
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 210 || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 900
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 225 || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 840
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 240 || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 780
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 255 || getTotalHomeworkScore() >= 720
                && getTotalTestScore() >= 285) {
            letterGrade = "G";
        } else {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return letterGrade;
    }

}
```

This class creates a student object, with values to be set from a text file. This next class creates an array of these student objects, as well as a few other things that aren't important at the moment. The important method right now is the setStudents method, which is creates the array of student objects:

```
public class CourseOffering {
    Student[] students;
    String description;
    double homeworkAverage;
    double testAverage;
    int passingStudents;

    public CourseOffering() {

    }

    public void setStudents(Student[] studentArray) {
        students = studentArray;
    }

    public void setDescription(String descript) {
        description = descript;

    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public double computeHomeworkAverage() {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            temp += students[i].getTotalHomeworkScore();
        }
        homeworkAverage = temp / students.length;
        return homeworkAverage;
    }

    public double computeTestAverage() {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < students.length; j++) {
            temp += students[j].getTotalTestScore();
        }

        testAverage = temp / students.length;
        return testAverage;
    }

    public int countPassingStudents() {
        int temp = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < students.length; k++) {
            if (students[k].getGrade() == "G") {
                temp++;
            }
        }
        passingStudents = temp;
        return passingStudents;

    }

}
```

Finally, this class is the driver that is running the entire thing:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CourseStatistics {
    static int numberOfClasses = 0;
    static int numberOfStudents = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student myStudent = new Student();
        CourseOffering myCourseOffering = new CourseOffering();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("gradesA5.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out
                    .println("Error opening file. Please make sure that you have a grades.txt file in the same folder as GradeCalculator.class");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        numberOfClasses = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numberOfClasses);

        myCourseOffering.setDescription(scanner.next()); // CSCE
        myCourseOffering.setDescription(scanner.next()); // 155A
        myCourseOffering.setDescription(scanner.next()); // -

        myCourseOffering.setDescription(scanner.next()); // Reads Semester
        System.out.print(myCourseOffering.getDescription() + " "); // Prints
                                                                    // Semester

        myCourseOffering.setDescription(scanner.next()); // Reads Year
        System.out.println(myCourseOffering.getDescription()); // Prints Year

        numberOfStudents = scanner.nextInt(); // Number Of Students
        System.out.println(numberOfStudents); // Prints number of students

        System.out.println("Name" + "\t" + "\t" + "Assignment Score" + "\t"
                + "Test Score" + "\t" + "Grade");

        myCourseOffering.students[0].setFirstName(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(myCourseOffering.students[0].getFirstName());

        // for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; i++) {

        // }

    }
}
```

Ok, now the part I am having difficulties with. This piece of code is where I am attempting to call the first index on the student object array and setting the .firstName value from reading the text file:

```
myCourseOffering.students[0].setFirstName(scanner.next());
        System.out.println(myCourseOffering.students[0].getFirstName());
```

But I keep the null pointer exception. The exception points to     myCourseOffering.students[0].setFirstName(scanner.next()); as the problem line, but I am not sure what the problem is. This is the text file I am attempting to read:

```
3
CSCE 155A - Fall 2011
4
Anthony Hopkins 80  90  95  87  80  78  25  17  20  22  21  24  19  22  21  23  24  21  20  25  20  55  56  110 30  20  25  8
John  Smith   99    95  82  72  64  52  15  14  11  21  25  12  19  20  21  23  21  12  12  10  15  50  50  60  25  15  20  9
Pan Mei     85  92  72  45  82  78  22  13  16  22  24  10  18  12  21  24  25  10  11  14  20  58  51  95  28  14  28  7
Rafael Vega    99   45  87  52  87  99  25  25  21  21  14  19  19  25  25  20  20  18  20  24  20  60  60  60  25  16  23  8
CSCE 155A - Spring 2012
1
Paul Kubi     80    90  5   87  80  0   25  0   20  22  21  24  19  22  21  0   24  21  20  25  20  0   0   0   30  20  25  8
CSCE 155A - Fall 2012
3
Tianna Delp   99    99  99  99  99  99  24  15  16  21  25  15  19  20  21  22  21  21  23  15  15  60  50  60  20  17  20  9
Taylor Delp   95    92  80  90  82  78  25  25  25  25  24  10  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  25  58  51  95  28  14  28  7
Rachel Valenz 99    45  87  52  87  99  25  25  21  21  14  19  19  25  25  20  20  18  20  24  20  60  60  60  25  16  23  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that when declare `myCourseOffering`

```
    CourseOffering myCourseOffering = new CourseOffering();
```

You are initializing the `myCourseOffering` class object, but the member `Student[] students` never gets initialized and remains `null`.

```
public class CourseOffering {
    Student[] students;          // never initialized, hence NULL
    String description;
    double homeworkAverage;
```

Thus initialize it (and other members to avoid future errors), preferably inside the constructor

```
public class CourseOffering {
    Student[] students;          
    String description;
    double homeworkAverage;
    double testAverage;
    int passingStudents;

    public CourseOffering() {
        this.students = new Student[100];          
        this.description = "";
        this.homeworkAverage = 0.0;
        this.testAverage = 0.0;
        this.passingStudents = 0;

    }
```

or you can initialize it outside in the main method like this

```
myCourseOffering.students = new Student[numberOfStudents];
```

Answer (score 1):

The value `myCourseOffering.students` is `null` because you haven't initialized the array.  An array in Java has to be initialized, as well as every instance in the array.

An array is instantiated using `new` and a specific size for the array - it looks like the number of students is provided on the previous line, so you'll want to read that and use it to instantiate:

```
myCourseOffering.students = new Student[10];
```

Also, you will want to initialize each entry, probably in some sort of loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number of students; i++) {
    myCourseOffering.students[i] = new Student();
    // populate properties of Student
}
```